# DataGridView - Problema na mudança nos nomes das colunas

Tags: c#

Tenho uma tabela com os seguintes campos na ordem em que foram criadas:

> idProdReceita, idReceita, Quantidade, Imagem, Descricao, Fornecedor, Medida, Unidade, Valor

Quando carrego o DataGridView no programa as colunas aparecem com os nomes Default dos campos. Até aí tudo normal.

** O que eu realmente desejo é alterar os nomes das colunas após trocar a ordem e visibilidade das mesmas. Não quero mostrar todos os campos no DataGridView.

Se eu tentar mudar os nomes das colunas do DataGridView programaticamente como mostrado abaixo, funciona:

```
        gridView.Columns["idReceita"].HeaderText = "ID";
        gridView.Columns["Imagem"].HeaderText = "Imagem";
        gridView.Columns["Descricao"].HeaderText = "Descrição";
        gridView.Columns["Unidade"].HeaderText = "Unidade";
        gridView.Columns["Quantidade"].HeaderText = "Quant.";
        gridView.Columns["Exclusao"].HeaderText = "Exclusão";
```

P.S. A última coluna mostrada [exclusao] é um botão que inseri no DatagridView em tempo de execução.

Abaixo pode-se ver como fica o Datagridview já com as colunas e visibilidades alteradas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Colunas que quero que apareçam no datagridview (ordem e visibilidade alterados):

> idReceita, Imagem, Descricao, Unidade, Quantidade, Exclusao

Nomes que quero que apareçam no lugar das colunas default:

> ID, Imagem, Descrição, Unidade, Quantidade, Exclusão

**O problema acontece quando altero a ordem e a visibilidade de algumas colunas (visible = false) e utilizo um método para automatizar a troca dos nomes. Apenas a primeira coluna troca o nome, o restante continua com o nome default.

Método utilizado:

```
private void TrocaNomeColuna(DataGridView gridView, string nomeCampo, string novoNome)
    {
        string[] campo = nomeCampo.Split(',');
        string[] titulo = novoNome.Split(',');

        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < campo.Length; i++)
            {
                if (gridView.Columns.Contains(campo[i]))
                {
                    gridView.Columns[campo[i]].HeaderText = titulo[i];
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Uso:

> TrocaNomeColuna(grid, "idReceita, Imagem, Descricao, Unidade, Quantidade, Exclusao", "Id, Imagem, Descrição, Unidade, Quantidade, Exclusão");

Imagem de como fica o DataGridView depois que executo o programa utilizando o método:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui você percebe que após a utilização do método só a primeira coluna foi afetada; o restante continuou mostrando os nomes default das colunas;

Tenho um método que me permite esconder e alterar a ordem das colunas, pelo menos esse funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está no parâmetro da chamada da função `TrocaNomeColuna`

Em vez de passar o parâmetro `nomeCampo` como:

```
"idReceita, Imagem, Descricao, Unidade, Quantidade, Exclusao"
```

Retire os espaços em branco e passe:

```
"idReceita,Imagem,Descricao,Unidade,Quantidade,Exclusao"
```

Ou de um `Trim` após aplicar o `Split`.

```
string[] campo = nomeCampo.Split(',').Select(p => p.Trim()).ToArray();
string[] titulo = novoNome.Split(',').Select(p => p.Trim()).ToArray();
```

Minha sugestão é que evite dar um simples `throw` nas exceptions. Talvez você mesmo tivesse percebido o erro.

```
catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Comment: O pior é que eu já havia pensado nisso alguns minutos antes da sua resposta. Só não tinha implementado o código ainda. Mas, o que você disse deu certo mesmo. No entanto acabei trocando os parâmetros do tipo string em List<string> com isso eliminei algumas variáveis. Mesmo assim muito obrigado pela dica.